# ffi-napi problem - Installing vosk (node.js) on Windows 11

Tags: node.js, windows, vosk

I tried a few things mentioned in this post. The npm install --global windows-build-tools command no longer works. Switching to python 2.7, cache clean then npm install, or reinstalling node.js also didn't help.

Any suggestions?

the site doesn't allow me to post a longer error log, here are some parts:

```
164 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
164 error gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
164 error gyp info using node@20.9.0 | win32 | x64
164 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.0 found at "C:\Users\Harvestworks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
164 error gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.7.34221.43) found at:
164 error gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
164 error gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
```

[Download the entire log](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/files/13342584/error.log.log)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not too late.
i had the same issue, after hours of digging, these few things i did got it to work:

1. use `vosk` package from npm, then `require('vosk')` in the test_xxx.js file directly.
2. downloaded model at the root directory(same as `package.json`)
3. nodejs using `mic` package, which need `arecord`(linux) or `sox`(mac/windows) installed. check the `mic` github page for details. In my case, this seems to be the culprit that cause the ffi-napi problem.

after these, everything works accordingly.

however, I found that the speed is slower, and not as accurate as the `python` counter part.

I am using Mac by the way.